# How to handle data from a Teltonika GPS device using sockets in Java

Tags: java, sockets, gps

I'm getting data from a Teltonika GPS device and storing it in my application. The first time I connect I get the data, however the device requires some kind of acknowledgment and it's waiting for that.

Can anyone explain how to handle data from a GPS device through java socket programming?

Comment: teltonika device .. in that data will be stored but once we are sending acknowledgment then only am getting raw-packet..

Comment: Is your question about socket programming or their data format? You must be more specific with your questions to get answers.

Comment: Maybe it needs IMEI number. For example: IMEI 123456789012345 shall be sent to the server as  000F31323334353637383930313233343. The server will send back 01

Comment: This information is quite confidential in nature and may be specific from one Teltonika GPS tracker device to another; you need to get the programming manual from Teltonika for full detail on how to send/read the Teltonika data for your device.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the device and the protocol used to communicate with it, but as a general rule you would need to make sure the socket is open and listening.

From the brief out-line of your problem I would think that the issue is that you are either forcibly closing the socket yourself, or you are not listening for a connection properly.

Does you code have a loop around a call to `Socket.accept()` - something like..

```
while (true) {
  Socket socket = server.accept();

  // handle the coms...
}
```

Basically, to keep communicating with something you need to keep accepting or 'listening' for responses, otherwise you will only get one response. The call to `accept` is a 
blocking call that basically waits for clients to connect...but if it is not called again, you have effectively stopped accepting or 'listening'

Answer (score 0):

Teltonika devices generally wait for acknowledgement after sending the data. Server's response should be number of decoded points (since Teltonika devices pack few points together, and after you decode their format, you need to respond with number of decoded gps points).

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your tracker first using below steps as in figure:

To initiate configuration process, configuration server sends binary initiation SMS (“Push” SMS) containing server host(ip address) and tcp port device should connect to and waits for TCP connection.

Upon reception of “push” SMS, device tries to establish TCP connection to configuration server using GPRS. If TCP connection attempt succeeds, server sends out configuration data to device over established connection, device confirms configuration reception and configures itself.

If device doesn‘t connect to server in TcpWaitTimeout time, server stops waiting for TCP connection, sends out configuration data using binary SMS, and waits for confirmation SMS from device. If confirmation SMS doesn‘t arrive in specified time, server assumes that configuration process failed.

[image]

**Reference file:**
https://sourceforge.net/p/opengts/discussion/579834/thread/6fd0ffe8/6213/attachment/FMXXXX%20Protocols%20v2.10.pdf